How to read cookie expiration date in Express?
I want to read the expiration date of a cookie.
This is how I set up a cookie:
res.cookie("tokenCookie", token, {
      secure: false,
      httpOnly: true,
      expires: dayjs().add(1, "hour").toDate(),
    });

I used the cookie-parser library and req.cookies returned the key value pair of the cookie and its value. However, the value doesn't include the expiration date of the cookie, only the value I assigned the cookie to store.
{
  tokenCookie: 'sample.auth.token'
}

How can I read or access the expiration date in the expires attribute?

Reading a cookie only gets you name and value, all the other parameters that were used when setting it (domain, path, expiry, ...) are not available. If you need this timestamp available afterwards for other purposes - then store it into an additional cookie, or make the value of the first one a JSON that contains both token value and expiry, or something like that.

You can open your browser developer tools (typically by hitting F12), find the "Network" pane and inspect the request headers to see what's being sent in the "Cookie" header.

Is your token a JWT? If so, is the cookie expiration date the same as the JWT? Regardless, you can add a additional expiration date in the token and read it from there.

Browsers handle cookie expiry so they don't pass the cookie's expiry value to the server. If you really need it server side you do something similar to this
while sending the cookie
const expirationDate = new Date();

const cookieValue = JSON.stringify({
  token: token,
  expires: expirationDate.toISOString(),
});

res.cookie("tokenCookie", cookieValue, {
  secure: false,
  httpOnly: true,
  expires: expirationDate,
});

and then parse the cookie value to get expiration date and token
const cookieValue = req.cookies.tokenCookie;

if (cookieValue) {
  const { token, expires } = JSON.parse(cookieValue);
  console.log("Token:", token);
  console.log("Expiration Date:", new Date(expires));
} else {
  console.log("Token cookie not found.");
}

